# C++ : Duda con includes

Tags: c++

habia buscado que para guardar datos tipo string en una variable era necesario incluir la libreria string y usar la siguiente funcion: `getline(cin,str)` pero probando me di cuenta que no es necesario incluir la libreria string ni para crear variables tipo string ni para hacer uso de esa funcion, porque es esto?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    string name;

    cout<<"Ingresa tu nombre completo: ";getline(cin,name);
    cout<<endl<<"Tu nombre es: "<<name;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En tu programa has incluido i<ostream> y con ella estas incluyendo implícitamente las otras librerias.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Algunas cabeceras de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) son mutuamente dependientes. En el caso que describes `std::getline` reside en la cabecera `<string>` pero esta cabecera es incluida en otras cabeceras que hagan uso de la clase `std::string` como por ejemplo la cabecera que otorga acceso a las funciones de lectura y escritura de consola `<iostream>`.

Sin embargo estas dependencias mutuas no están estandarizadas, lo que implica que diferentes compiladores pueden tomar decisiones diferentes en cuanto las cabeceras incluidas en otras cabeceras… esto puede provocar que si confías en la inclusión implícita tu código compile en unos compiladores pero no lo haga en otros y es por esto que se insiste en la necesidad de incluir las cabeceras que se usen, aunque *parezca* que no es necesario.